# Unity 3D: Loading an image from device memory shows an image with Question mark

Tags: image, unity-game-engine

Am taking a snap and setting that image as background to other scene,but finally that background is showing a question marked image..[image]

FYI the image already exists, i have checked that with File.exists(). and here is the code snippet i have used.

```
IEnumerator DisplayTexture() {
        WWW www = new WWW(SelfiateUtils.SnapImagePath);
        yield return www;

        BGTexture.mainTexture = www.texture;
        //Trace.text="Assaigned successfully";
        if (www.error == null) {

        }    
    }
SelfiateUtils.snapImage is the string url where i have saves the file.
```

can any one help me to fix this.
thanks.. :)

Comment: `The data must be an image in JPG or PNG format. If the data is not a valid image, the generated texture will be a small image of a question mark.` from the `www.texture` unity documentation  http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW-texture.html

Comment: Its a PNG image. I came to know that the Byte length is 0 :( DO u have any idea how to resolve this? @Lefty

Comment: ... wouldn't that indicate that the image hadn't actually been returned? :s

Comment: Its fixed,.. Should add "file://" in the front..

Comment: To the front of what?  Loading?  Unloading?  The path everywhere?  More specificity would be super helpful!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just to complement the answer in the comments and give it more visibility, as stated by Sharath, one must add "file://" as as prefix to load image files (jpg, jpg) in iOS.

This particularly important to remember when loading streaming assets. This prefix must be added before Application.streamingAssetsPath in iOS and also when running the app in the Unity Editor (Win and MacOS). In Android this prefix should be omitted.